# MySQL get back the same value twice from a SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, distinct

If I do:

```
SELECT a, a FROM myTable
```

I can get back the "a" value two times, and that's fine, it works.
But I want to do something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a) AS a1, DISTINCT(a) AS a2 FROM myTable
```

Of course I do know and do understand why you cannot use DISTINCT twice. And in fact I do not want it :) More than that, if possible I want to 'optimize' it somehow, since it's already been calculated. I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(a) AS a1, a1 FROM myTable
```

but still no luck...

Example, if the table contains

```
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccc
aaa
```

I want the output to be

```
aaa | aaa
bbb | bbb
ccc | ccc
```

PS: The "why" is because I need the output of the query to be passed to a function that needs those parameters "duplicated" in that order, and while I theoretically *could* edit and duplicate those values manually before calling the function, I would rather let MySQL give me back the correct string.

Comment: What if there are two different `b` related with the same `a`?

Comment: And what "function" would that be, that can't use a passed parameter twice?

Comment: Perhaps I'm dense, but I don't understand what you want here.  What would the resulting output look like?

Comment: I edited the question and removed "b", just causing confusion. The function is a custom one that gets as input an array of associative arrays representing the table and according to some specific syntax for each field, it prints the table plain and/or with a custom style and/or it calls a custom PHP function that acts on that parameter.

Comment: @derpirscher perfect, I didn't try that! That's what I needed... If you paste it as the answer I will accept that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DISTINCT`  always applies to the entire row of your result set. You cannot make a single column distinct. Just use

```
select distinct a, a from table
```

Answer (score 0):

use **DISTINCT** keyword to avoid getting same value twice.

> select Distinct a, a from table_Name